How do I configure proxying to a domain with nginx receiving a response?
At the moment I am just getting a redirect in the browser to https://acestream-engine-latest.onrender.com/ and getting a response. When trying a simple http request just a 502 error.
What am I doing wrong?
events {}

http {
    server {
        listen 80;

        location / {
            proxy_pass https://acestream-engine-latest.onrender.com/;
            proxy_set_header Host $host;
            proxy_set_header X-Real-IP $remote_addr;
            proxy_set_header X-Forwarded-For $proxy_add_x_forwarded_for;
            proxy_set_header X-Forwarded-Proto $scheme;

            proxy_set_header Accept-Encoding "";  # Tell the backend not to send gzip
            gzip off;
            sub_filter 'https://acestream-engine-latest.onrender.com' 'http://127.0.0.1';
            sub_filter_once off;
            sub_filter_types application/json application/vnd.apple.mpegurl application/x-mpegURL;

           
        }
    }
}

The task is as follows:

http request to 127.0.0.1/(request)
Redirect the request to https://acestream-engine-latest.onrender.com/(request)
Receive the response, pre-processing it on 127.0.0.1.

